# tap function with touch swipe

Tags: jquery, swipe

I have the following code which executes functions when the user swipes .carousel. However I'm not too sure how to use the tap function, I want to execute a function when the user taps a link within the .carousel element. How would I write this? Thanks!

```
 $(".carousel").swipe({
      excludedElements: "button, input, select, textarea, .noSwipe",
      swipeLeft: function() {
        $('.carousel').trigger('next', 4);
      },
      swipeRight: function() {
        $('.carousel').trigger('prev', 4);
      },
      tap: function(event, target) {
       ...............
      }
    });
```